# What is the fastest approach of having a list stored on drive in python?

Tags: python, file, vector, storage

I'm working with (really) big data in python and for each input I need to compute a single number which is required later and may be changed. So basically I  have a vector (list) of integers.

When size of vector is `O(10^9)` or more, it's impossible to fit it into a memory. Hence, obviously, I need to save it to a file on hard drive.

So what I need is a class with a pair of functions handling a file containing integer vector.

**Example:**

```
class FileVector:
    def __init__(self, file_name)
    def update(self, position, value)
    def read(self, position)
```

For simplicity, please assume that the size of vector is fixed and known. Also let the file be created before first usage of the class and all we care about is how to read/update it **as fast as possible.**

**So the questions** - what file format should I choose in order to maximize read/update speed? Alternatively, is there any already implemented solution, preferably in standard library? I tried to find some but failed.

My ideas so far:

- Each number on single row, reading using readline
- Numbers on single line, separated by whitespaces
- Some binary format maybe?

Please note that neither `update` nor `read` may load the whole vector into memory at once.

Comment: This may be off the topic but why don't you use a database? Since here the r/w speed is your biggest concern..You can just define a table and set the position to be the index.

Comment: @Yang Well that was my original solution, however I can't force the users to install databases. All in all, I'd like to stick to python as much as possible in order user to simply install my software using `pip install <package>` without any "non-pip" dependencies (user may use various OS etc.). The updates and reads won't be so frequent (basic estimation is each value read and updated 1000 times) but I still want to have it as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think python ships with [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: @Matt I'll check it, anyway maybe another solution? Using only standard library or some pip packages?

Comment: sqlite is in the stdlib, check the link in my last comment. I am also almost completely positive that the c lib has shipped with python since 2.5. I'm not sure about other pip packages, but you could do this with a binary file and file.seek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10^9 is a few gigabytes - that can still fit into RAM, even on laptops. Python libraries like [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) can help with this - they offer specialized array type with lower memory footprint and some nice mathematical functions.

As a *really* big data I consider hundreds of terabytes or more... Distributed frameworks like [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/) are usually used for processing data of these terabyte volumes.

But if you want just a file-based array, I would go with [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/mmap.html):

```
import struct
from mmap import mmap

class FileVector:

    number_size = len(struct.pack("<i", 0))

    def __init__(self, file_name, initial_size, default_value=0):
        try:
            self.f = open(file_name, "r+b")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.f = open(file_name, "w+b")
            fill = self._number_to_bytes(default_value)
            for i in range(initial_size):
                self.f.write(fill)
            self.f.flush()
        self.m = mmap(self.f.fileno(), 0)

    def close(self):
        self.m.close()
        self.f.close()

    def update(self, position, value):
        self.m.seek(self.number_size * position)
        self.m.write(self._number_to_bytes(value))

    def read(self, position):
        self.m.seek(self.number_size * position)
        return self._bytes_to_number(self.m.read(self.number_size))

    def _number_to_bytes(self, n):
        return struct.pack("<i", n)

    def _bytes_to_number(self, b):
        return struct.unpack("<i", b)[0]

fv = FileVector("data", 10**9)
print(fv.read(1000))
fv.update(1000, -42)
print(fv.read(1000)) # should return -42
```

But it is of course not as fast as it would be in C/C++ etc. - on my notebook it managed to do 500 000 updates or reads per second, but which is probably more than a "normal" database could achieve. Also mmaped files can be shared between processes if parallelization would be needed.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it. You could also add the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to make access more list like

Comment: Also, note that this will only work for 32 bit integers (c actually only guarantees 16 bits, but less than 32 is rare)

Comment: @Matt: I wanted to use `c_int32` from `ctypes` with defined size, but I could not find how to convert it back from bytes to Python number, so I went with `struct`.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find one either. You could use `l` in the pack/unpack formats for long (at least 32 bits) or `q` for long long (at least 64 bits)